# Piping output from Git Bash to clipboard

Tags: git, clipboard, git-bash

I often need to relay my Git output to others. The best way I know how is by doing this:

```
Right-click Git Bash title bar > Edit > Mark > Select lines > Enter
```

Now everything I selected is in my clipboard. But I'd like to do it on the command line.

In Windows, you can pipe console output to your clipboard like so:

```
C:\> dir | clip
```

But when you try to do that in Git Bash, here's what happens:

```
> git branch | clip
sh.exe": clip: command not found
```

Is there a way to pipe Git Bash output to my clipboard in Windows?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Well, actualy `git branch | clip` works fine for me. `clip` command just calls `clip.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32\`. Make sure you have `clip.exe` installed somewhere in your `PATH`.

Comment: This worked! After some searching I found that [you have to set your `PATH` variable inside git-bash](http://superuser.com/questions/600409/sh-exe-clip-command-not-found), not just as an environment variable.

Comment: Wow, magical. But the answer here is slightly annoying. For most of us, we don't want to only do a copy of git branch. Here's how to copy the contents of a file: `cat [file] | clip`. And now you can ctrl+v it wherever you want yay.

Comment: Great tip! Worked out of the box!

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 54):

copy thing.txt to clipboard

```
cat thing > /dev/clipboard
```

Put contents of clipboard into thing.txt

```
cat /dev/clipboard > thing.txt
```

I aliased these things to pbcopy and pbpaste so I feel like I'm on my mac.

Comment: imo this is the best answer

Comment: The best answer - this handles utf-8 encoding correctly. Piping to `clip.exe` does not.

Comment: OMG! `/dev/clipboard` works on Windows GitBash!

Answer (score 5):

@[madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750510/madhead)'s answer is correct - the `PATH` variable must be set from within git-bash. Here's an elaboration on how to fix this issue, courtesy of [Cairnarvon's answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/600409/sh-exe-clip-command-not-found):

To check what `PATH` is currently set to:

```
> echo $PATH
```

And to set it, assuming a 64-bit architecture:

```
> export PATH="$PATH:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows/SysWOW64"
```

Result of `git branch | clip`:

```
* master
  dev
  dev_foo
```

Answer (score 3):

For Mac users, you can simply pipe the git diff output to `pbcopy` utility. Something like

```
git diff | pbcopy
```

And paste the changes anywhere. No need to first highlight all the git difference from the terminal and then paste it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to copy Git Bash console's entire content:
`Right click anywhere on the console > Select All`

Keyboard shortcut for the same: `Ctrl+Shift+A`
Enable this keyboard shortcut by enabling `Options > Keys > Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts`.

mintty version: 3.4.4 (x86_64-pc-mysys) [Windows 19042]